# Create ssh key pairs to copy elsewhere without messing up my personal ssh setup

Tags: ssh, command-line, osx, ssh-agent

In my Mac I already have a personal RSA key pair under `~/.ssh`
I would like to create a couple of RSA keys in my Mac but for another computer. So I don't want to run some ssh command and replace my existing keys somehow.
Just create some key pairs for users A and B in a custom dir so that I can copy them where I need to and be sure that nothing of my personal SSH settings is replaced/broken.
How can I do this safely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-f` flag

eg

```
% ssh-keygen -f /tmp/foobar
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /tmp/foobar.
Your public key has been saved in /tmp/foobar.pub.
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `ssh-keygen` and when asked for a name for the keypair, use something other than the default path (and optionally filename).  You can then find the generated keypair in the location you specify.

Comment: I would be more comfortable if I avoided the `~/.ssh` to be honest.

Comment: When you run `ssh-keygen`, literally the first thing it asks is for the file into which to save the key.  Including the path.

Comment: So `~/.ssh` is the default and only used if nothing else is provided? I was concerned that `~/.ssh` is somehow modified/updated regardless

Comment: Only if you use the default for the key file into which to write; if you specifiy another path, your `.ssh` directory is left untouched.  It does _not_, for example, add the generated public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: 1) Is the full file path supposed to be there? Or will it create a missing dir? 2) From what I understand ssh-agent knows only about `~/.ssh`. So I was wondering if there is the option to specify a full file name for the key eg `~/extrakey/somekey_rsa` how would this key be found by ssh agent?

Comment: 1) Yes, you specify the full path to the file.  2) you can use a file in any location, e. g. `ssh-add /path/to/obscure/location/id_secretserver`